# How do I prepend and append any groups of numbers in a string with a dash using preg_match and preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying something like this -

```
$foo = "foo555bar25foobar1";
if(1 === preg_match('~[0-9]~', $foo, $matches) { 
$bar = preg_replace($matches, "-".$matches."-", $foo);
};
echo $bar;
```

The result I'm looking to achieve is:
foo-555-bar-25-foobar-1-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$foo = "foo555bar25foobar1";
$bar = preg_replace('/\d+/', '-$0-', $foo);
echo $bar;
```

Comment: Wow so much more simplified since I'm using array of patterns in my particular case. I am getting better at regex patterns.